# CSS animation on mouse leave

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So I'm trying to do something like tiles or what netflix does. I have a box that I am trying to make grow on mouse hover and reduce in size when the mouse leaves. So Far I have this.

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 12.5%;
  padding-left: 12.5%;
  padding-bottom: 6.25%;
  padding-top: 6.25%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px grey;
  animation-name: downsize;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.link:hover {
  animation-name: resize;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-right: 14.5%;
  padding-left: 14.5%;
  padding-bottom: 8.25%;
  padding-top: 8.25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="/public/MM/EnterUp">
    <div class="link" style="margin-right: 15px;">
      Enter Up
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/public/MM/EnterUp">
    <div class="link" style="margin-right: 15px;">
      View Ups
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I used [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/DifferentTransitionsOnOff/)
to get it to reduce after the mouse hover. My problem is that unlike CSS-Tricks, when you load the page I don't want the `downsize` animation to run, just after the mouse leaves. Anyone have a solution? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should use JQ or pure JS  to make this animation because mouseout event not exist in css, you can make two classes each one have animation and on mouseover remove those classes and add the class which hold the zoom animation, onmouseout remove scale class and add the class which hold the rotate.

Comment: Sad day, you would think that they would have created two separate selectors for this. How does CSS-Tricks do it then?? Cuz i don't think their's uses javascript, could easily be wrong though. 
https://css-tricks.com/examples/DifferentTransitionsOnOff/

Comment: what type of animation you want after mouseLeave?

Answer (score 5):

While there is no equivalent of the `mouseleave` or `mouseout` events in CSS, you can achieve the same behaviour by applying the "exit" transition to the selector and then overriding it with the "enter" transition using the `:hover` pseudo-class, like so:

```css
div{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    transition:font-size .5s ease-out,line-height .5s ease-out,width .5s ease-out;
    width:100px;
}
div:hover{
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:125px;
    transition:font-size .25s ease-in,line-height .25s ease-in,width .25s ease-in;
    width:125px;
}
/* HOUSEKEEPING */
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;}
body,html{height:100%;}
body{align-items:center;display:flex;justify-content:center;}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
```

Alternatively, if the `transition` you wish to apply is the same in both cases, only reversed then there is no need to override it in your `:hover` selector.

Comment: That's great! It's 4:00am here so I'll try it tomorrow and give you an update :)

Answer (score -1):

you can simply just use [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for the padding

something like this in your case should do it:

```css
.nav {
        position: relative;
        top: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .nav a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .link {
        font-size: 24px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%);
        display: inline;
        padding-right: 12.5%;
        padding-left: 12.5%;
        padding-bottom: 6.25%;
        padding-top: 6.25%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px grey;
        transition: padding 0.4s ease-out;
    }
    .link:hover {
        font-size: 32px;
        padding-right: 14.5%;
        padding-left: 14.5%;
        padding-bottom: 8.25%;
        padding-top: 8.25%;
}
```

The key here is the use of:

```css
transition: padding 0.4s ease-out;
```