# Play CSS animation backwards on cursor release?

Tags: html, css

How do I play my CSS animation backwards after I release my cursor from the Image? I want it not to jump back to normal but I want it to play the animation backwards to look nice.

Here's my code:

```css
    #portrait {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    scale: 65%;
    }
    
    #portrait:hover {
    animation-name: OnHover;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes OnHover {
        from {scale: 65%;}
        to {scale: 75%;}
    }
```

```html
    <div id="portrait">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Portrait">
    </div>
```

Comment: My first answer was junk; this one works, I just tested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37158075/8104777

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Works perfectly fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to use `transform: scale` you can simply add transition instead.

```css
#portrait {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
scale: 65%;
transition: transform 1s ease;
transform: scale(.6);
}

#portrait:hover {
transform: scale(.75);
}

.image{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="portrait">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but it flickers around a little bit. i came to the conclusion to make a OnRelease animation, which is the reverse of OnHover and I set it into #portrait and that works.

Comment: Okay, post your answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div id="portrait">
            <img id="img" src="/assets/portait.png" alt="Portrait">
        </div>   



#portrait {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

#img {
    animation-name: OnRelease;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    scale: 65%;
}

#img:hover {
    animation-name: OnHover;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes OnHover {
    from {scale: 65%;}
    to {scale: 80%;}
}

@keyframes OnRelease {
    from {scale: 80%;}
    to {scale: 65%;}
}
```